# Multiple alarms not working properly Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

Here is what I tried in my code. Multiple alarms not working properly Android

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    int time1 = Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
    time1 = time1 * 1000;
    final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long r4 = time1 + System.currentTimeMillis();
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, r4, pendingIntent);
```

Anyone has any idea what is wrong,
some help will be appreciated, thank you:)

Comment: What exactly is not working? And reformat your code snippet, it's really hard to read.

Comment: Sorry ci_. with this code,  Alarm fires instantly

Comment: Someone Plzz help me out . I am new to stack Overflow. Sorry if my code is in improper format.

Comment: Can you explain again, what exactly your question is, "Multiple alarms not working" or "alarm fires instantly". Also explain how do you determine this, do you have log output somewhere? Also show some relevant broadcast receiver code/manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you are assigning time to trigger alarm `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,r4, pendingIntent);` is wrong.

The time in seconds you get from user is needed to set in `Calendar` and then assign that time in the `alarmManager.set();`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, time1);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Your code would be like,

```
AlarmManager alarmManager;
alarmManager=( (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

int time1 = Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, time1);

final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,_id , intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: ohhh thanks apurva. But my previous code is working. Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Comment: Apurva and ci_ thanks a lot you guys have  made my day

Comment: ohh I m new to stack overflow thanx apurva. Can u answer my another question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204992/how-to-make-ui-for-multiple-days-selection-android